# Extract XBRL facts to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, xbrl

I would like to cycle through several hundreds of XBRL-files automatically and gather certain specific pieces of data and paste them into an excel sheet. I managed to get the "tangential code" working, but cannot answer the core question.

E.g., in the XBRL file I need the value of this fact, reported against the concept `pfs:GainLossBeforeTaxes`:

```
<pfs:GainLossBeforeTaxes
    unitRef="U-EUR"
    decimals="INF" 
    contextRef="CurrentDuration">1091134.68</pfs:GainLossBeforeTaxes>
```

==> I need to obtain 1091134.68

This is doubtlessly something which is easy with Regex, but I cannot seem to get this working. And time constraints are also a thing for me, so I would like to obtain some sort of minimal viable product so far and later on expand that, but at this point the code is more of a means to an end, rather than the endproduct (analysis) itself.

So far, I came up with the following:

```
Sub EDI_Input()

Dim myFile As String
Dim textline As String
Dim StartPos As Integer
Dim EndPos As Integer

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Open myFile For Input As #EDI
Do Until EOF(EDI)
Line Input #EDI, textline


If InStr(textline, "NonRecurringFinancialCharges") <> 0 And InStr(textline, "CurrentDuration") <> 0 Then

Endpos = InStr(textline, "</pfs:NonRecurringFinancialCharges><")


result = Left(textline, Endpos - 1)
StartPos = InStr(textline, "Char(34)&CurrentDuration&Char(34)&>")
textline = Left(textline, StartPos + 18)
Debug.Print (textline)

End If

Loop
```

I keep stumbling on the "invalid call procedure or argument error", possible because I load to many data in my string.

Anybody who has any opinion on how to get at least a partially working programma - in that way I can at least partially start my analysis - Or a tutorial for beginners/experience with this problem?

Comment: From what you have written, you just need to find the first substring of digits and dots in your string.  But I suspect your written specifications are incomplete.

Comment: The XBRL specifications are available here: https://specifications.xbrl.org/ This is a very good question and a very common use case for many people looking into fiscal reports. Grepping substrings from an XBRL instance is a bit risky, because there is a precise way to proceed to get values from an XBRL instance together with their context, and then filter based on the data model.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? You should be able to do what you're looking for with an open source processor such as Arelle or Gepsio, depending on the version of Excel you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I recommend using an XBRL processor, for example [Arelle](http://arelle.org/), which is open source. If I correctly remember, you should be able to export facts to formats like CSV and import it into Excel.

Otherwise, you will end up reimplementing an XBRL processor in VBA. There are many involved details to consider in order to get the correct values (joining with context, considering dimensions, etc). Values could be reported against a concept for multiple periods, etc.

An XBRL processor will do that out of the box.